# How does subtracting an address reference work?

Tags: arrays, c, memory-address, pointer-arithmetic

I think the value of `z` should be 40 because `a[5]` has 20 elements, and the space between it and `a[3]` also has 20 elements. However, the actual value of `z` is 2.

Can anyone explain this concept?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a[10][20];
    int z = &a[5] - &a[3];
    printf("%d\n", &a[3]); // the address information is 6421740
    printf("%d\n", &a[5]); // the address information is 6421900
    printf("%d\n", z);     // z value is 2. why?
}
```

Comment: Printing an address using `%d` format specifier causes undefined behaviour. Use `%p` and cast the argument to `(void*)` Nowadays addresses and `int` values frequently have different sizes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the C Standard (6.5.2.1 Array subscripting)

> 2 A postfix expression followed by an expression in square brackets []
> is a subscripted designation of an element of an array object. The
> definition of the subscript operator [] is that E1[E2] is identical to
> (*((E1)+(E2))). Because of the conversion rules that apply to the
> binary + operator, if E1 is an array object (equivalently, a pointer
> to the initial element of an array object) and E2 is an integer,
> E1[E2] designates the E2-th element of E1 (counting from zero).

So the expression `a[3]` is evaluated like `*( a + 3 )`. As a result the expression `&a[3]` is equivalent to the expression `&*( a + 3 )` that in turn is equivalent to `( a + 3 )`.

The same way the expression `&a[5]` is equivalent to the expression `( a + 5 )`.

So the difference `&a[5] - &a[3]` is evaluated like `( a + 5 ) - ( a + 3 )` that yields `2`. That is between these two addresses `&a[5]` and `&a[3]`  there are only two elements of the type `int[20]`.

On the other hand if you would write `( int * )&a[5] - ( int * )&a[3]` that is if the array would be interpreted as a one-dimensional array of the type `int` you would get `2 * 20` that yields the expected by you value `40`.

Comment: Technically, that last case would be undefined behavior because you'd be performing pointer arithmetic between two pointers that are not elements of the same array.

Comment: @dbush They are elements of the same array. The  memory occupied by the array is interpreted as a one-dimensional array.

Comment: No, there is no basis in the language spec for the idea that casting the pointers to type `int *` causes the storage of `a` to be reinterpreted as a one-dimensional array for the purposes of the rules for pointer arithmetic. That may be a common manifestation of the undefined behavior that occurs in such a case, but make no mistake: the behavior of that last pointer difference is indeed undefined, just as much for those pointers as for two pointers into separately declared arrays.

Comment: However, the preceding parts of this answer present a creative and useful way to understand the behavior of pointer subtraction.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Well, consider the code int *a = malloc( sizeof( ingt[2][10] ) ); Is it undefined behavior? No, the code is well-formed.  If you have a two-dimensional array you may interpret it as a one-dimensional array. The extent of memory is aligned and there is no gaps between elements of the array.

Comment: I do not see how the well-definedness of the `sizeof` operator for objects having array of array type implies that the standard allows for reinterpreting such objects in whole as one-dimensional arrays (except inasmuch as the representation of *any* object can be read as an array of character type).  This is not a matter of alignment or gaps, only of what the standard actually says.  Sure, you *may* interpret an array of arrays of T as a 1-D array of T, but the standard does not define what happens if that involves overrunning the bounds of one of the array-of-T members of the 2D array.

Comment: @JohnBollinger If you have a pointer p to an object and there is after the object there is another object correctly aligned then the expression pm+ 1 will point to that object.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, yes, if `p` is an element of an array that contains at least one more element after `p`, but that doesn't support your case.  Otherwise, if there happens to be an object `q` immediately following `p` in the address space, then `&p + 1` *compares equal to* `&q`, but the former does not *point to* `q`, as dereferencing it produces UB.  And this is closely related to the fact that, again, the spec does not define behavior for interpreting a 2D array in whole as a 1D array.

Comment: @JohnBollinger There is nowhere in the standard said that it is undefined behavior. Otherwise using malloc or realloc will invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: Which "it", Vlad?  How about "If the result [of a pointer addition] points one past the last element of the array object, it shall not be used as the operand of a unary `*` operator that is evaluated" (C17 6.5.6/8)?  And dynamically allocated objects have their own rules about type -- this is why the strict aliasing rule needs to introduce "effective type".

Comment: @JohnBollinger Consider code void *p = malloc( sizeof( int[2][2] ) ); int ( *p1 )[2] = p; int *p2 = p; *p2 = 10; printf( "%d\n", p1[0][0] ); Where is there undefined behavior?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, I don't see where anything I said implies that that particular code would have undefined behavior.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow The rules for effective type in 6.5p6 allowed for allocated objects to have their effective type changed.  So what you have it fine, but the following is UB as per 6.5.6p8:  `int a[2][2];  a[0][3]=1;`

Comment: @dbush The effective type of any element of a two-dimenional array having the type specifier int is int. So you may use the pointer of the type int * to access such an element.

Comment: Yes, @Vlad.  Nobody said anything different.  But in ISO C, the behavior around pointers depends not just on pointer type and value, but also on the *derivation* of that value.  The dependency on derivation is arguably something that C picked up during the standardization process, as it is not clear in (say) the first edition of K&R.  But even C90 has language equivalent to C17 6.5.6/8.

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow Thank you. This post is very clear. Is the last line should be `( int * ) a[5] - ( int * ) a[3]` instead of `( int * )&a[5] - ( int * )^a[3]` ?

Comment: @Creek It was a typo.:)

Answer (score 8):

Pointer arithmetic is done in the units of the pointed-to type.

In this case `a[5]` and `a[3]` are both elements of an array of type `int [20]`, and `&a[5]` and `&a[3]` both have type `int(*)[20]`.  They are 2 array element apart, so the difference between them is 2.

It doesn't matter that the underlying type is also an array.

Answer (score 2):

> and the space between it and a[4] also has 20 elements

No, the `element` of a[4] has the type of array of 20 `int`s. It is not an int.

It is called pointer arithmetics. It does not work on **bytes** or **chars** only on the type of pointer.

`&a[3]` has type of pointer to `int[20]`. `&a[5]` has type of pointer to `int[20]` and it located two (2) `int[20]` arrays from `&a[3]`.

It is much easier to explain using a simpler example.

```
int main(void)
{
    double dbl[10];
    for(size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
    {
        size_t distance = (dbl + i) - dbl;
        size_t distancebytes = (char *)(dbl + i) - (char *)dbl;
        printf("dbl + %zu is %zu double and %zu bytes from dbl\n", i, distance, distancebytes);
    }
}
```

```
dbl + 0 is 0 double and 0 bytes from dbl
dbl + 1 is 1 double and 8 bytes from dbl
dbl + 2 is 2 double and 16 bytes from dbl
dbl + 3 is 3 double and 24 bytes from dbl
dbl + 4 is 4 double and 32 bytes from dbl
dbl + 5 is 5 double and 40 bytes from dbl
dbl + 6 is 6 double and 48 bytes from dbl
dbl + 7 is 7 double and 56 bytes from dbl
dbl + 8 is 8 double and 64 bytes from dbl
dbl + 9 is 9 double and 72 bytes from dbl
```

https://godbolt.org/z/KoKn8sM5b